# i want to convert below query to mysql query as we are migrating some procedures from sql server to mysql

Tags: mysql

How to convert below sql server insert to mysql insert

i have table with (id,name,age) columns.

insert into student values(@id, 'jack' + convert(varchar(5), @id), 12)

create procedure insert_student
as
begin 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.student;
declare @id int 
select @id = 1
while @id >=1 and @id <= 1000
begin

```
insert into student values(@id, 'jack' + convert(varchar(5), @id), 12)
select @id = @id + 1
```

end
end

Answer (score 1):

SQL INSERT INTO Syntax [source link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

It is possible to write the INSERT INTO statement in two forms.

The first form does not specify the column names where the data will be inserted, only their values:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

The second form specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

So with your table

```
INSERT INTO student (id,name,age)
VALUES (null,jack,12);
```

As you are migrating, so highly suggest `mysqli` or `PDO` as `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: i want data to be inserted as below to mysql

Comment: 11 jack11 12
12 jack12 12
13 jack13 12
14 jack14 12
15 jack15 12
16 jack16 12
17 jack17 12
18 jack18 12
19 jack19 12
20 jack20 12
21 jack21 12
22 jack22 12

Comment: id=11, name=jack11 age=11

Comment: the code in answer is just for reference, you can change it to `VALUES (11,jack11,11);` but remember if `id` col is `auto-increment` and if it already has value `11` it will throw error, so that's why i put `null`

Comment: auto-increment is not defined for id column , name is not null , what is the equivalent syntax to do insert in mysql  , i want value after 'Jack+number  to be incremented'

Comment: it's the one way if the data you are trying to insert already has incremented numbers `INSERT INTO student (id,name,age) VALUES ('11','jack 11','11');` the other way around is with `counter` and `foreach` but i don't know the how you are trying to insert the data and another way is use migration tool kit here http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/migration/

Comment: convert this sql server procedure to mysql

Comment: added procedure to my  question/first comment, thanks